# Regular expression for capturing all skin-tone variations of an emoji

Tags: regex, emoji, oniguruma, emoji-tones

I'm trying to use a regex to capture tweets containing the substring  at least twice, so I'm using an unsophisticated `^.+  .+  .+$`.  However this doesn't match strings which instead contain, for example, .

Is there a smart way I can capture an emoji with any or none skin-tone variation, without just putting each one in a row (like `[]`)?

Comment: Are they Unicode Characters?

Comment: How are these emoji represented? Unicode? If yes, what is their value?

Comment: Ok, this question *definitely* requires the regex flavor to be known - what language/regex lib are you using?

Comment: @Druzion Ah, yes thank you, this was a prompt I needed to probe a little further into how emojis are represented on twitter.  I've now figured an answer so can share it below.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, yikes, this is a question I don't fully understand, sorry.  However, I've now found what I was looking for, so I'll include it in the answer below.

Comment: @Cai what I meant is: the answer will be very different, depending on the regex engine that you'll use. PCRE/.NET/Python/Java/JavaScript/etc... I could just tell you to use `(?=)\X` but that wouldn't work in several of these.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Ah, ok, got it. Thanks. As it happened I was just using Textmate, which claims to use the Oniguruma regex library, which likely explains why your suggestion didn't work for me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to comments above, I've found that emojis I've encountered on twitter are unicode, and skin-tone variations are combining characters in the range `1f3fb`–`1f3ff`.

http://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Modifiers_Table

So for me what I wanted was `[\x{1f3fb}-\x{1f3ff}]?`, with `[\x{1f3fb}-\x{1f3ff}]?` being something I can then drop next to any unmodified emoji to include skin-tone variations.