# Getting unexpected result from emoji count?

Tags: swift, emoji

Why is

`"".characters.count == 1`

and not equal to 3? Is there a way to get my expected result of 3?

Comment: I don't know about swift specifically, but "" is made up of 4 characters.

Comment: Compare also [How to know if two emojis will be displayed as one emoji?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104152/how-to-know-if-two-emojis-will-be-displayed-as-one-emoji), which shows a method to get `3` as the "composed characters count" of `""`.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: `""` consists of 4 Unicode scalars, but is a single "extended grapheme cluster". Interestingly, `""` counts as s single grapheme cluster as well.

Answer (score 0):

A probable cause is that Swift counts any sequence of regional indicator characters as one cluster. Your string is basically `"USUSUS"`. But since it is displayed as three independent grapheme clusters, the count should intuitively be 3. When you put other characters between the flags, they are counted as expected.