# Deleting Emoji Bug

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I followed this link [Find out if Character in String is emoji?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757193/find-out-if-character-in-string-is-emoji) to try to limit the amount of characters my text field even with emojis. According to this link, I have to count emojis based on their glyphs and everything is working except for one little bug, when my glyph count is reached, it won't let me delete the string anymore.

Here's the code the handle the character limit using UITextField Delegate

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

var canEditString : Bool = false

if textField == self.descTxtField {

    // Description Text Field
    if textField.text != nil || textField.text != "" {

        let currentString = textField.text
        if (currentString?.containsEmoji)! {
            print("I have an emoji")
            let glyphCount = currentString!.glyphCount
            print(glyphCount)
            canEditString = glyphCount <= descriptionLimit
        }else {
            print("I have no emoji's")
            let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
            //print(currentCharacterCount)
            if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
                return false
            }
            let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
            canEditString = newLength <= descriptionLimit
        }
    }
    return canEditString


} else {

    // Number Text Field
    let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
    if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
        return false
    }
    let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
    return newLength <= numberLimit
}
}
```

Comment: You should use `guard` rather than `let` to reduce your pyramid of doom a bit

Comment: `range.length` and `string.characters.count` are not *compatible:* the first counts UTF-16 code units and the latter counts extended Unicode grapheme clusters. Have a look at the various answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index.

Comment: You might be interested in [How to know if two emojis will be displayed as one emoji?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104152/how-to-know-if-two-emojis-will-be-displayed-as-one-emoji)

Comment: Thanks for your help @MartinR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/StringManifesto.md)

**Swift 4**

Emojis now have a character count of 1, making it a lot easier to keep track of character counts in Strings.