# String substring with flag emoji in Swift

Tags: swift, string, substring, emoji

While doing further research for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift-3) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift-3#comment66655934_39677704), I have come across the following problem in Swift 3.

```
let str = "Hello"
print(str[str.startIndex])
```

I would expect the result to be

```
 // the Swiss flag
```

Instead I get

```
 // Swiss, German, US flags
```

Why is this happening? How do I solve it?

Comment: Possible workaround at [How to know if two emojis will be displayed as one emoji?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104152/how-to-know-if-two-emojis-will-be-displayed-as-one-emoji).