# Get starting position of a substring not counting emoji as one character ios

Tags: ios, swift, string, range, substring

i'm trying to find the starting positions of a substring within a string. It's only returning the correct index if it's just characters without any emoji. However, when special characters like emojis are used, the returned index is not correct. I want to count each emoji or character as one character. Here is my code:

```
extension String {
    func index(of string: String, options: CompareOptions = .literal) -> Index? {
        return range(of: string, options: options)?.lowerBound
    }
    func indexes(of string: String, options: CompareOptions = .literal) -> [Index] {
        var result: [Index] = []
        var start = startIndex
        while let range = range(of: string, options: options, range: start..<endIndex) {
            result.append(range.lowerBound)
            start = range.upperBound
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104152/how-to-know-if-two-emojis-will-be-displayed-as-one-emoji

Comment: What results do do get and what do you expect? A concrete example would be helpful.

Comment: for example: ".. lol" index start of lol is 3. But if i replace for example the ".." by a laughing face emoji, i get a 5 index starting position of lol.

Comment: Thanks Leo for your answer but that still doesn't solve the issue!

Comment: @mei02 I didn't answer only removed the unnecessary code

Comment: @mei02: The return value is a `String.Index` and the result is exactly what you need when indexing another string. If you want the count the distance in characters then compute `distance(from: startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)`

Comment: thank you @MartinR for your answer! I have a question. When making an NSRange it needs a location as a parameter but this location doesn't take the emoji as one character. Any possible solution for that?